# Unable to activate Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

1. I am new to wordpress, I installed wordpress correctly but after installation when i am trying to 'visit site', its showing **Page Not Found** [Screenshot of page-not-found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVW96.png)
2. Whenever I am trying to install and activate a new theme, it get installed but at the time of activation it showing the following error [Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jk00.png).

Please help me, without this I would not be able to start learing wordpress.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue on your theme file. So you first try to fix that issue in your theme files then you can activate or install that theme.